# Load next image from array on mouse enter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, var

On page load, a random background image is applied to all `$("#image").siblings` from an array of images defined under `var images =`.

On `.mouseenter` the selected image fades out, and a new background image is applied, before it fades back in. How can I ensure this is always the next image from the array, rather than a random image as it is currently?

HTML

```
<section id="grid" class="desktop-image">        
    <div class="image-grid">
      <div id="image" class="image01"></div>
      <div id="image" class="image02"></div>
      <div id="image" class="image03"></div>
      <div id="image" class="image04"></div>
    </div> 
</section>
```

JS

```
// Random Image

var images = ['PK1.jpg','PK2.jpg','PK3.jpg','PK4.jpg','PK5.jpg','PK6.jpg','PK7.jpg','PK8.jpg','PK9.jpg','PK10.jpg'];

$("#image").siblings().css({'background-image': 'url(assets/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});


//Images Fade Out/In

$('.image02').mouseenter(function(){
    $(".image02").addClass("hide");
    setTimeout(function() {
    $(".image02").css({'background-image': 'url(assets/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});                        
        },1000);    
    setTimeout(function() {
    $('.image02').removeClass('hide');
        },6000);
    });

$('.image03').mouseenter(function(){
    $(".image03").addClass("hide");
    setTimeout(function() {
    $(".image03").css({'background-image': 'url(assets/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});                        
        },1000);        
    setTimeout(function() {
    $('.image03').removeClass('hide');
        },6000);
    });

$('.image04').mouseenter(function(){
    $(".image04").addClass("hide");
    setTimeout(function() {
    $(".image04").css({'background-image': 'url(assets/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});                        
        },1000);        
    setTimeout(function() {
    $('.image04').removeClass('hide');
        },6000);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sample code where I have commented the `setTimeout` as it will produce extra issues. It might be done later.
The main idea is to set own array of images as `data` attribute at each image. Then on `mouseenter` we got this array, we `shift` it i.e. first item goes to the variable *next* and then add it to the end using `push`. The image in next is set as *background-image*. Simple and effective.

```js
// Random Image
var base = 'https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/goescat/macaron/128/'; 
var images = [
  base+'atom-icon.png',
  base+'calc-icon.png', 
  base+'burp-suite-icon.png',
  base+'calligra-krita-icon.png',
  base+'deluge-icon.png',
  base+'code-blocks-icon.png'
];

$(".image").each(function() {
  $(this)
    .data('own', images)
    .css({'background-image': 'url(' + images[0] + ')'});
  images.push(images.shift());
});


//Images Fade Out/In
$('.image').mouseenter(function(){
    var $element = $(this);
    $element.addClass("hide");
//    setTimeout(function() {
      var own = $element.data('own');
      var next = own.shift();
      own.push(next);
      $element
        .css({'background-image': 'url("'+next+'")'});                        
//    },1000);    
    setTimeout(function() {
      $element.removeClass('hide');
    },6000);
});
```

```css
.image{width:128px;height:128px;padding:0px;margin:10px;border:1px solid #000; float:left}
.hide {}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="grid" class="desktop-image">        
    <div class="image-grid">
      <div id="image1" class="image"></div>
      <div id="image2" class="image"></div>
      <div id="image3" class="image"></div>
      <div id="image4" class="image"></div>
    </div> 
</section>
```

Comment: thank you! I've got the code working. However, I need all images to start on the same image, which is chosen randomly on page load. Then when each image is hovered on, it changes to the next image in the list, irrespective of other image changes. So in your example: on page load all images randomly begin as the atom-icon.png, then when individually hovered, they would each change to next item in the list; calc-icon.png. And so on.. Hopefully that makes sense?

Comment: I think this you are able to make on your own ... it's just changing initialisation lines `$(".image").each(function() {$(this).data('own', images).css({'background-image': 'url(' + images[0] + ')'}); images.push(images.shift()); });`. If you think this answer wasn't just a time waste you may vote it up or/and mark it as best answer.

Comment: I have successfully made all the images load as the same random image on load. However I can't work out how to make the image variable shift uniquely for each image. I assumes it would be ```unshift()```. Any chance you could help me out? its the last thing I have to solve on this build! Many thanks